# Getting value from CompositeDisposable RXJava

Tags: android, rx-java2

How can I get return value from below code :

```
          private fun <T, R> requsetMovie(call: Observable<T>, transform: (T) -> R, default: T): Either<Failure, R> {
                val myCompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
                myCompositeDisposable?.add(call
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe({//I need to return value},{e->//I need to return value}))
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use interface to return result, you can`t return result directly
example in java :

```
public void getPassengers() throws Exception {
    getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager()
            .doGetPassengers(new GetPassengersRequest(getCurrentTime(), 0))
            .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
            .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                getNavigator().disMissLoading();
            }, throwable -> {
                getNavigator().showMsg("");
            }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Single.blockingGet](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#blockingGet--) for synchronous call

```
// example 
doGetPassengers(new GetPassengersRequest(getCurrentTime)).blockingGet()
```